# Hiding Username and Password Text on Sensitive Website----(Selenium Python/Pytest )

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I want to hide username/password in my ~home environment_ variable and retrieve in in my code using the `import os` module. For some reason, whenever I try to get the output of the password

Code:

```
import os

user_pass = os.environ.get(['tk-user'])
username_field = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")
self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").click()
username_field.send_keys(user_pass)
```

I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'tk-user'
```

Comment: Have you added the password word to your environment variables and correctly named it 'tk-user'? The `KeyError` is likely due to the variable not being set.

Answer (score 0):

The `user_pass` line should look more like this:

```
user_pass = os.environ.get('tk-user')
```

Comment: value = (None,)

    def keys_to_typing(value):
        """Processes the values that will be typed in the element."""
        typing = []
        for val in value:
            if isinstance(val, Keys):
                typing.append(val)
            elif isinstance(val, int):
                val = str(val)
                for i in range(len(val)):
                    typing.append(val[i])
            else:
>               for i in range(len(val)):
E               TypeError: object of type 'N